# How do I draw text with GLUT / OpenGL in C++?

Tags: c++, opengl, text, glut

How do I draw a text string onto the screen using GLUT / OpenGL drawing functions?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are two ways to draw strings with GLUT

[glutStrokeString](https://linux.die.net/man/3/glutstrokestring) will draw text in 3D

[image]
<sub>(source: [uwa.edu.au](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/oldstuff/glut/opengl4.gif))</sub>

and [glutBitmapString](https://linux.die.net/man/3/glutbitmapstring) will draw text *facing* the user

[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://openglut.sourceforge.net/openglut_fonts.png))</sub>

Comment: Please note that you will need [freeglut][1], as opposed to glut, to use glutBitmapString.


  [1]: http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I know its an old question, I have glut.h it just when I try to use either of the method it will say identifier "glutBitmapString" or "glutStrokeString" is undefined any ideas ?

Comment: @Jonathan superjoe30 is right. glutBitmapString and glutStrokeString are not in the original GLUT implementation. But, if you want to use GLUT I'd suggest looking into using either freeglut or openglut which both have them. If I recall correctly the original GLUT implementation has not been updated since 1998 due to its licensing scheme so freeglut and openglut was started to solve that problem and add new features etc. See http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 11):

```
void RenderString(float x, float y, void *font, const char* string, RGB const& rgb)
{  
  char *c;

  glColor3f(rgb.r, rgb.g, rgb.b); 
  glRasterPos2f(x, y);

  glutBitmapString(font, string);
}
```

And you can call it like;

```
RenderString(0.0f, 0.0f, GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, "Hello", RGB(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
```

Comment: error: request for member ‘r’ in ‘rgb’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’