# Using text in OpenGL -- GLUT?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I've been using GLUT for menu'es in openGl programs for some time now, but have a hard time coming to terms with it being so hard to get text into the gl-scene. Is there no way do use the text system GLUT uses for menus inside the scene?

if so how is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some other libraries that may be of interest here, such as [freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) (in particular look at the [font rendering functions](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php#FontRendering)). Alternatively it shouldn't be too hard to write your own function that simply prints a string.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538661/how-do-i-draw-text-with-glut-opengl-in-c) for more alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

Printing x coords of mouse location

```
char gMouseXLoc[25];
void drawString (void * font, char *s, float x, float y, float z){
     unsigned int i;
     glRasterPos3f(x, y, z);

     for (i = 0; i < strlen (s); i++)
          glutBitmapCharacter (font, s[i]);
}

void displayMethodName {
     ...
     drawString(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, gMouseXLoc, 0, 0, 0); 
}

void mouseMotionForGlut(int x, int y){
     double xloc = x;
     sprintf(gMouseXLoc, "%2.15f", xloc);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can bother to translate the page and perhaps the comments, this class was done by a student at my school and it's incredibly easy to use. Basically all you have to do is load the font you want to use and then use the print function. 2 lines and it works extremely well. I've used it in some openGL applications and it's really easy to use.

Link: http://4.eepp.ca/?p=phont (Tutorial + code example, in french)

Download: http://4.eepp.ca/files/phont-1.zip

Ps. It uses GL.h and GLU.h