# How to label points to a rectangle in openGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

Trying to create a Rectangle and label the corners using A,B,C,D . I am successfully able to draw a rectangle, however unable to label the corners.

Here is the source code so far:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* GLUT callback Handlers */
static void resize(int width, int height)
{
    const float ar = (float) width / (float) height;

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-ar, ar, -1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 100.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity() ;
}

static void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3d(1,0,0);
        glVertex3f(-1,-1,-10);
        glColor3d(1,1,0);
        glVertex3f(1,-1,-10);
        glColor3d(1,1,1);
        glVertex3f(1,1,-10);
        glColor3d(0,1,1);
        glVertex3f(-1,1,-10);
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}


static void key(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case 27 :
        case 'q':
            exit(0);
            break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

static void idle(void)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

/* Program entry point */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(10,10);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);

    glutCreateWindow("GLUT quadPoly");

    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(key);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);

    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);

    glutMainLoop();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

How to label the corners in the rectangle?

Comment: What does labeling the corners mean? do you mean passing variables to glVertex3f?

Comment: Nope, label the corners, A,B,C,D at each corner of the rectangle .

Comment: I don't think that is specific enough, so you want to render the letters A, B, C and D at each corner?

Comment: If that is what you want, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538661/how-do-i-draw-text-with-glut-opengl-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to label the corners in the rectangle?

The glut liberary function [`glutStrokeCharacter`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node78.html) renders a stroke character. Stroke characters are rendered by drawing line primitives. The maximum top height of a character in a font is 119.05 units; the minimum at the bottom is 33.33 units. The width of a character can be get by [`glutStrokeWidth`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node79.html). The character is rendered to the origin of the current model view projection matrix.

The following function renders a character with a size `h` to position `x`, `y`, `z`. The alignment can be set by `left` and `top`:

```
void LabelStroke(char c, float h, bool left, bool top, float x, float y, float z)
{
    float scale = h / ( 119.05f + 33.33f );
    float xo = x;
    float yo = y;
    if ( left )
    {
        int w = glutStrokeWidth(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, c );
        xo -= h * (float)w / ( 119.05f + 33.33f );
    }
    if ( top )
        yo -= h * (float)119.05f / ( 119.05f + 33.33f );

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(xo, yo, z);
    glScalef(scale, scale, scale); 
    glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, c); 
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Use the function somehow like this:

```
void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3d(1,0,0);
        glVertex3f(-1,-1,-10);
        glColor3d(1,1,0);
        glVertex3f(1,-1,-10);
        glColor3d(1,1,1);
        glVertex3f(1,1,-10);
        glColor3d(0,1,1);
        glVertex3f(-1,1,-10);
    glEnd();

    float size = 0.5f;
    float offsl = size * 0.7f;
    glColor3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    LabelStroke( 'A', size, true,  true,  -1.0f, -1.0f, -10.0f );
    LabelStroke( 'B', size, false, true,   1.0f, -1.0f, -10.0f );
    LabelStroke( 'C', size, false, false,  1.0f,  1.0f, -10.0f );
    LabelStroke( 'D', size, true,  false, -1.0f,  1.0f, -10.0f );

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

See the preview:

[image]

With the glut library function [`glutBitmapCharacter`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node76.html), a bitmap character can be rendered. A bitmap character is rendered by drawing pixels (e.g.   [`glDrawPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glDrawPixels.xml)). The position of the character can be set and moved by [`glRasterPos`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRasterPos.xml) and respectively [`glBitmap`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBitmap.xml):

```
void LabelBitmap( char c, bool left, bool top, float x, float y, float z  )
{
    int w = glutBitmapWidth( GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, c );
    glRasterPos3f( x, y, z );
    glBitmap(0, 0, 0, 0, left ? -w : 0, top ? -24 : 0, NULL);
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, c); 
}

void display(void)
{
    .....

    glColor3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    LabelBitmap( 'A', true,  true,  -1.0f, -1.0f, -10.0f );
    LabelBitmap( 'B', false, true,   1.0f, -1.0f, -10.0f );
    LabelBitmap( 'C', false, false,  1.0f,  1.0f, -10.0f );
    LabelBitmap( 'D', true,  false, -1.0f,  1.0f, -10.0f );

    .....
}
```

Note, the current color ([`glColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml)), which is to be used to render the character, has to be set before [`glRasterPos`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRasterPos.xml) is called.
The current raster position also includes some associated color data and texture coordinates. When `glRasterPos` is called, then the current colors and texture coordinates replace the colors and texture coordinates stored in the current raster position’s associated data.

Preview:

[image]