# Is there a way to display text in C++ using OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

I would like to spread some text on the screen using OpenGL in C++. Is there any example source or method for reference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I draw text with GLUT / OpenGL in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538661/how-do-i-draw-text-with-glut-opengl-in-c)

Comment: [check this](https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/Text-Rendering)